# How can I get the Rails asset pipeline to produce source maps?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'd like to have Rails produce source maps alongside the compiled coffeescript/minified JS, for better error logging. There doesn't seem to be comprehensive documentation on the net on how to do this, yet, though. Has anyone done this?

I'm on Rails 3.2 and Heroku.

Comment: source map - what is it?

Comment: Source maps are a way of mapping obfuscated/compiled/compressed source code back to its original form.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: did you see or hear if it is possible at all for now (in RoR development environment)?

Comment: There has been mention of this being possible in edge rails, and I have seen some hacks for coffeescript maps only.

Comment: hm... interesting... for now i just use "Reformat Code" feature in my IDE RubyMine. It reformats code to semi-readable state (return rows and tabs basically)... but, of course, it becomes not the same as original was

Comment: all answers talking about coffeescript here. I'm writing vanilla JS. Any insights from anyone?

Comment: If you are using Sprockets 3.x, you can extend the `uglifier` minimizer to add sourcemaps via this blog article: https://blog.experteer.engineering/generating-sourcemaps-with-sprockets-3-and-uglify.html

Answer (score 13):

Rails supports source maps for minified JavaScript! Rails relies on [Sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets) for asset compilation, and source maps support was added to Sprockets in [this pull request](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/pull/311).

Comment: Your Edit's from 2014 - Just wanted to confirm that the branch has been released?

Comment: Sprockets 4.x is not yet out. You can track releases here: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/releases

Answer (score 4):

If you don't really want source-maps, but instead just want **line numbers in coffee-script compile exceptions** try this:

It used to be that just having coffee-rails in your Gemfile would produce exceptions with line numbers in the original coffeescript source. Then, they disappeared with a line-number-less exception. I did some digging, and I found that `coffee-script-source` 1.5.x gave line numbers in the compilation exceptions, while `coffee-script-source` 1.6.x did not. I believe is a bug, and I wouldn't be surprised if this was "fixed" in the future.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-script-source', '~> 1.5.0' # 1.6 doesn't include line numbers in exceptions
```

Then you'll get exceptions like ('coffee-script-source', '~> 1.5.0')

```
Showing /Users/.../app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #12 raised:

SyntaxError: missing } on line 15
  (in /Users/.../app/assets/javascripts/app.js.coffee)
```

Instead of ('coffee-script-source', '~> 1.6.3')

```
Showing /Users/.../app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #12 raised:

SyntaxError: missing }
  (in /Users/.../app/assets/javascripts/app.js.coffee)
```

Comment: This can also be fixed with [this patch that embeds the line information in the error message](https://github.com/josh/ruby-coffee-script/pull/21) for the `ruby-coffee-script` gem.

Answer (score 3):

Tested this. It works. https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps. However it makes your asset rendering much slower.

Comment: If you're using source maps, [this patch](https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps/pull/16) fixes issues with line numbers for syntax errors `coffee-rails-source-maps` gem.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it should work: http://alexspeller.com/2012/09/15/Source_maps_for_coffeescript_in_rails.html

Though, keep in mind the warning at the end:

> **Important Note**: this rather brutal hack replaces the normal
>   coffeescript compiler by shelling out to the CoffeeScriptRedux
>   compiler, which is not in fact finished. This is just a proof of
>   concept, you probably shouldn’t use it.

So I wouldn't recommend running this in production, but if you have a staging environment (also on Heroku, also with minified Javascript) it might be useful.